# undefined reference to 'dlopen'

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc

Estou tentando carregar um arquivo `.so`, mas está aparecendo esse erro do título. Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <dlfcn.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
      void *abrir;
      abrir = dlopen("EZClient.so", RTLD_NOW);

    if(!abrir)
    {
      printf("%s\n", dlerror());
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As implementações das funções `dlopen` e `dlerror` estão em uma biblioteca chamada `libdl.so`.

Assim, para que vc compile este programa, usando o g++, tem que executar a seguinte linha de comando

```
g++ -o programa programa.cpp -ldl
```

ou seja, adicionar a biblioteca usando a opção `-ldl`